# WMIC - how to check if return empty value?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, wmic

I'm making a batch file to make log of computer (I need save some informations before format PC's on my work...)

So I found some commands to create this log, see:

```
rem -- Windows Version
wmic OS get Caption, OSArchitecture, ServicePackMajorVersion /format:htable > "%~dp0Config %computername%.html"

rem -- User Account
wmic USERACCOUNT get Caption,Name,PasswordRequired,Status /format:htable >> "%~dp0Config %computername%.html"

rem -- Installed Programs
wmic product get Description, InstallDate, Name, Vendor, Version /format:htable >> "%~dp0Config %computername%.html"
```

The problem is on this command:

```
wmic nicconfig get Description, MACAddress, IPAddress, IPSubnet, DefaultIPGateway, DNSServerSearchOrder, DHCPEnabled /format:htable >> "%~dp0Config %computername%.html"
```

On this case, I need show only adapters that have **Mac Address**...

On other case I do this to show only Enable Adapters:

```
wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed, PNPDeviceID /format:htable >> "%~dp0Config %computername%.html"
```

But now, I need check for not empty values. How I can check if return not empty value? for take only values that have Mac Address?

I try this but does't work:

```
wmic nicconfig where MACAddress!='' get Description, MACAddress, IPAddress, IPSubnet, DefaultIPGateway, DNSServerSearchOrder, DHCPEnabled /format:htable >> "%~dp0Config %computername%.html"
```

Sorry for my bad english =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WMIC uses a SQL dialect. An empty string (0 length string) is not the same as NULL (no value).

```
wmic nicconfig where "MACAddress is not null" get ...
```

Comment: How would I get the only adpaters that have an "IPAddress" it doesn't look to work in the same way: wmic nicconfig where "IPAddress is not null" get description....